# Bash Command Nested conditional statements failing, but why

Tags: bash, logic

I have a bash script that runs many conditional statements, but when I run the script, it only hits the following line: `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`

```
touch /tmp/converted.json
tool test --json --all-projects | tee >> /tmp/converted.json
ret=$?
set -o pipefail

#no vulns
if ((ret == 0)); then
  echo "Hooray!"

#found vulns
elif ((ret == 1)); then
then                    
  #check single project
  if [[ $firstchar == "{" ]]
  then         
    echo "SINGLE PROJECT"
  elif [[ $firstchar == "[" ]]
  then
    echo "MULTIPROJECT"
  else
    echo "didnt get a single or multiproject"
  fi
#error with your command
elif ((ret == 2)); then
then
  echo "An error occurred"

#no manifest
elif ((ret == 3)); then
then
  echo "Ensure your repo has a proper required manifest file"

else
  echo "Something else occurred"
fi
```

Thus, why does this continue to hit `if((ret==0))` condition?

Thanks

Comment: Why would the exit status be `1`? If the file exists and can be read, in all likelihood the exit status of `head` is `0` and you'll never go past the first condition.

Comment: These are vendor specific exit codes I am trying to adhere to

Comment: `are vendor specific exit codes` vendor specific exit codes of `head`? what implementation are you using?

Comment: `$?` is reset by every command that runs, including tests like `[ $? -eq 0 ]`. If you want to run multiple tests on a single command's exit status, you need to store it in a variable first (or use `case`). (I'm pretty sure this has been asked & answered before, but I can't find a duplicate right now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` has the exit status of the **last** command executed. The last command at `elif [ $? -eq 1 ]` was `[` executed at `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]      # executes `[`
then 
    : dont care
elif [ $? -eq 1 ]    # $? here has a nonzero the exit status of `[`
```

Just save the exit status to a variable before calling any command right after executing the command you are interested in. In bash you may use arithmetic expansion `((...))`.

```
some_command
ret=$?
if ((ret == 0)); then
    : dont care
elif ((ret == 1)); then
```

Comment: so I implemented this logic, but its still hitting `$ret=0` .. ?? See updated code please

Comment: `set -o pipefail` Your code, after the edit, correctly checks the exit status of `tee`. Set `pipefail` before calling the pipe..

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk - just one last question, so i understand, what is `set -o pipefail` actually doing

Comment: The docs are [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-set), search for `pipefail`. With `pipefail` set, the exit status of the whole pipe will be the first non-zero exit status of the first left-most command. Normally, the exit status of the pipe is equal to the exit status of the right-most command. There's also `PIPESTATUS` variable that may be more suitable.